# Are Ethereum Contracts Vulnerable to Hash Table Poisoning Attacks?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, evm, attacks, hash-algorithm

Does anybody know something about this? I know that in general terms we will say not, but looking on the internet I found that isn't sure the answer to the question: 
**Can the EVM’s Internal Associative Array be Exploited?**.

Which makes more sense, because a Hash Table poisoning attack may be "impossible" in terms of gas costs (at least this is how I see it, I'm not an expert on this subject)

If anyone knows about this, or any papers/articles related it'll be appreciated.

Thanks on advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found some info here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3k4h3w/basic_questions_about_the_ethereum_evm_and_state/

Maybe you can start by reading this.

> EVM memory is transient. The EVM is not really a virtual machine (VM has a strong connotation for many) - it's just an interpreter for the EVM assembly language. As the interpreter runs, it maintains a stack (where each element is 32 bytes) and a memory byte-array, and has access to the contract's storage tree. The stack and memory byte-array are dropped when the execution completes. But yes, every single node runs the transaction - at any point in the execution, the state of the stack, the memory-byte array, the program counter, and the storage should be identical on each node.

Hope it helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Found this article, maybe is interesting for you!

https://hackernoon.com/are-ethereum-contracts-vulnerable-to-hash-table-poisoning-attacks-a4d9241e16c4

Comment: Hi there. Link-only answers are discouraged because the link could go dead or be moved at any time. Could you summarise the contents of the link in an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote the article ([Are Ethereum Contracts Vulnerable to Hash Table Poisoning Attacks?](https://hackernoon.com/are-ethereum-contracts-vulnerable-to-hash-table-poisoning-attacks-a4d9241e16c4)) linked by kr0.

The short and sweet of it is solidity mapping types are not hash tables.  They don't hash the key, mod that hash into a predictable location in a smaller array.  They fully SHA3 (or more specifically the variant keccak256) the key AND the memory address of the map itself and store the value in the contract's 2^256 sized virtual memory space.  So collisions would require collisions in SHA3 itself.

This is also why you can't iterate over the mappings.

Comment: WHOOO!! Appreciated man, nice job with that work.